# The value from a mat-option disappear when I edit another property

Tags: angular, angular-material, submit, angular6

I'm using Angular 6 and Material Angular in my project. If I edit one of the properties other than 'tipo', when I submit the form, the value of 'tipo' disappears. But when I edit only the 'tipo' property, this does not happen. How can I fix this? Thank you.

HTML file:

```
<form [formGroup]="updateForm" class="edit-form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Tipo" formControlName="tipo" #tipo>
      <mat-option value="Conta Corrente">Conta Corrente</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="Conta Poupança">Conta Poupança</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="Caixinha">Caixinha</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button type="submit" (click)="updateConta(tipo.value, identificacao.value, saldoInicial.value, agencia.value, cc.value)" [disabled]="updateForm.pristine || updateForm.invalid" mat-raised-button color="primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

TS file:

```
  updateConta(tipo, identificacao, saldoInicial, agencia, cc) {
    this.contaService.update(this.id, tipo, identificacao, saldoInicial, agencia, cc).subscribe(() => {
      this.snackBar.open('Conta atualizada com sucesso', 'OK', {
        duration: 3000
      });
      this.goBack();
    });
  }

  goBack() {
    this.router.navigate(['/contas']);
  }
```

Comment: Based on the code we are seeing, this should work. But there is not really enough code to reproduce the issue. Best would be if you could create a stackblitz to showcase the issue. Also, why are you using template reference values instead of the form values??

Comment: Hi. I'm kind of new in that. This app was build following a Youtube course. The code from that component is here: https://github.com/seeschweiler/mean-stack-angular-6-part-4/tree/master/frontend/src/app/components/edit

Thanks.